# How to map values in R?

Tags: r, plyr

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following :

```
library(plyr)

obs=c(1,4,4,5,6,7,8,3,3)

from_v1=unique(obs)

to_v2=c(11,44,55,66,77)  #  1 --> 11 , 4 ---> 44 , 5 --->55 etc 

mapvalues(obs, from = from_v1, to = to_v2 )
```

Here i'm willing to map :

```
1 -->  11
4 ---> 44 
5 ---> 55
6 ---> 66
7 ---> 77
```

However , 8 and 3 don't have images ( mapped values ).

In such cases , I only need to map values to themselves ( 8 --- > 8 and 3 --- > 3 ).

The previous code gives this error :

```
Error in mapvalues(obs, from = from_v1, to = to_v2) : 
  `from` and `to` vectors are not the same length.
Execution halted
```

Also the used values  ( 7 -- > 77 , etc ) are just special examples that i used to simplify the pb and doesn't have a real sense !

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is simpler?

```
dplyr::coalesce(to_v2[match(obs, from_v1)], obs)
#[1] 11 44 44 55 66 77  8  3  3
```

---

If you want to continue using `plyr::mapvalues` append the remaining from values to to values.

```
obs = c(1,4,4,5,6,7,8,3,3)
from_v1 = unique(obs)
to_v2 = c(11,44,55,66,77)
to_v2 = c(to_v2, tail(from_v1, length(from_v1) - length(to_v2)))

plyr::mapvalues(obs, from = from_v1, to = to_v2 )
#[1] 11 44 44 55 66 77  8  3  3
```